# SSL serverHello message length tampered

Tags: ssl

In the SSL client, I am receiving a serverHello message with tampered message length like below.

"16 03 00 00 35 02 00 08 00... "

Here, "00 08 00" is message length which is coming as 2048 bytes. But in the next record, it sends "serverCertificate & serverHelloDone" messages.

So, in the client side, it waits to read 2048 bytes.  but  messages "serverHello, serverCertificate, serverHelloDone" are not having 2048 bytes combinedly. So, still client waits to read pending message (socket is blocking socket). So, it just waits in recv and never comes out.

I would like to know how applications should handle this situation. Is there any way in SSL protocol, we can identify this. If not possible, how applications should handle this situation to come out ?

Thank you !

Regards
Satish.